# Mixing vcpkg with brew packages in one cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

Is there a way that I can use packages installed by vcpkg and brew simultaneously in modern cmake? Some packages are not available in vcpkg, some packages do not come with config.cmake file when installed by brew. For example libpqxx when installed with brew won't install the `libpqxx-config.cmake` file. On the other hand `apache-arrow` currently cannot be installed by vcpkg.

Comment: both brew and vcpkg do not force any content on `CMakeLists.txt`. `CMakeLists.txt` just contain respective`find_package` and those package managers make this `cmake` function to work properly. So basically your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Fair point. Suppose if you have set a toolchain to use vcpkg. Now you want to use apache-arrow from the brew installation. so a solution would be the set the brew path in `find_package(Arrow CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/lib/cmake/arrow NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`. This one loads the dependencies of the arrow package by looking into packages installed by vcpkg, which is not what we want. Then you end up by writing `find_package` recursively for all the dependencies.

Comment: A workaround: pick this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/17975) in vcpkg, then you can use arrow with vcpkg

Comment: you can, but you'll probably have to make your own "package finding" routines by making liberal use `find_file`, `find_library`, `find_program`, etc.